# What does ### mean in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was searching the site of apple and I found this in their code `_###` what does the three # mean, or is it just nothing useful at all? Found it here: http://images.apple.com/v/macbook-pro/e/scripts/features_retina.js

Source:

```
(function () {
    var c = AC.Class({
        initialize: function (a) {
            this._element = AC.Element.getElementById(a);
            this._viewer = null;
            this._showOnScroll = new AC.ShowOnScroll(this._element, {
                threshold: 0.6,
                timeInView: 0.05
            });
            this._showOnScroll.setDelegate(this);
            AC.Object.synthesize(this);
            if (!AC.Element.isElement(this.element())) {
                return false
            }
            this.setupViewer();
            if (AC.Detector.isCSSAvailable("transition")) {
                AC.Element.addClassName(this.element(), "can-animate");
                this.viewer().setDelegate(this)
            }
        },
        setupViewer: function () {
            var h = this.element();
            var b = AC.Element.selectAll(".gallery-content", h);
            var g = AC.AutoGallery.Types.Registries.gallery.__lookup["image-fadein"].getOptions();
            var a = new AC.ViewMaster.Viewer(b, h, h.id, g);
            this.setViewer(a)
        },
        willAnimate: function (m, k, l, b) {
            var a = (m.orderedSections.indexOf(l.id.replace("MASKED-", "")) === 1);
            var n = this.element();
            var o = false;
            var p = function () {
                if (!o) {
                    b();
                    o = true
                }
            };
            if (k) {
                k.setOpacity(0)
            }
            if (l) {
                l.setOpacity(1)
            }
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                if (a) {
                    AC.Element.addClassName(n, "second-section")
                } else {
                    AC.Element.removeClassName(n, "second-section")
                }
                n.addVendorEventListener("transitionEnd", p, true);
                window.setTimeout(p, 910)
            }, 10)
        },
        visitorEngaged: function () {
            this.showOnScroll().stopObserving();
            AC.Element.addClassName(this._element, "animate")
        }
    });
    var d = AC.Class({
        initialize: function (a) {
            this._element = AC.Element.getElementById(a);
            if (AC.Detector.isCSSAvailable("transition")) {
                AC.Element.addClassName(this._element, "can-animate")
            }
            this._showOnScroll = new AC.ShowOnScroll(this._element, {
                threshold: 0.6,
                timeInView: 0.05
            });
            this._showOnScroll.setDelegate(this);
            AC.Object.synthesize(this)
        },
        visitorEngaged: function () {
            this.showOnScroll().stopObserving();
            AC.Element.addClassName(this._element, "animate")
        }
    });
    AC.onDOMReady(function () {
        var b = new d("flash-chart");
        var t = new d("wifi-chart");
        var a = new AC.BatteryClock("clock-wrapper-1", $("clock-wrapper-1"), {
            angleHours: 60,
            angleMinutes: 720,
            duration: 2,
            initialMinutes: 0,
            initialHours: 210,
            backgroundAngleHours: 270,
            fillStyle: "#80e869",
            animatedFillStyle: "#5bcc41"
        });
        var q = new AC.BatteryClock("clock-wrapper-2", $("clock-wrapper-2"), {
            angleHours: 30,
            angleMinutes: 360,
            duration: 2,
            initialMinutes: 0,
            initialHours: 210,
            backgroundAngleHours: 240,
            fillStyle: "#80e869",
            animatedFillStyle: "#5bcc41"
        });
        if (AC.Environment.Feature.cssPropertyAvailable("transform")) {
            var r = $("ambient-backlit-keyboard");
            r.addClassName("ambient-backlit-keyboard-prepped");
            var p = new AC.ShowOnScroll(r);
            var o = false;
            p.setDelegate({
                visitorEngaged: function () {
                    if (o === false) {
                        r.addClassName("ambient-backlit-keyboard-complete")
                    }
                    o = true
                }
            })
        }
        var u = !AC.Detector.isIEStrict();
        var w = new AC.ViewMaster.Viewer(AC.Element.selectAll(".av .gallery-content"), AC.Element.select("#av-gallery"), "av-gallery", {
            silentTriggers: true,
            useKeyboardNav: true,
            shouldAnimateContentChange: u
        });
        if (AC.Environment.Feature.canvasAvailable()) {
            var s = AC.Element.select("#flash .hero-container");
            var v = AC.Element.select("#flash .flow");
            var x = {
                flow: null,
                init: function () {
                    var g = ".jpg";
                    var f = (!AC.Environment.Feature.isHandheld() && AC.Environment.Feature.isRetina()) ? "_2x" : "";
                    var m = "/105/media/us/macbook-pro/2013/flash_hero_flow" + f + "/";
                    var e = "flash_hero_flow" + f;
                    var k = AC.require("flow/playerFactory");
                    var h = new AC.ShowOnScroll(v, {
                        threshold: 0.9,
                        timeInView: 0.5
                    });
                    var l = [m + e + "_keyframe" + g, m + e + "_endframe" + g];
                    var i = m + e + "_###" + g;
                    var j = m + e + "_manifest.json";
                    this.flow = k(v, l, i, j, {
                        superframes: false,
                        keyframeCache: false,
                        benchmark: false
                    });
                    this.flow.frameRate = 30;
                    this.flow.on("canplaythrough", function () {
                        h.setDelegate({
                            visitorEngaged: function () {
                                x.flow.play()
                            }
                        })
                    })
                }
            };
            x.init();
            AC.Element.addClassName(s, "enhanced")
        }
    })
}());
```

Comment: Show the code where you found this.

Comment: It sounds like user-defined variable, i.e. the developers of the site define and use this variable for their needs.

Comment: `#` is not a valid character in JavaScript variable names...

Comment: Please post some code; it can mean anything and it depends on the context

Comment: It's still a valid property name.

Comment: Hm, didn't thought of it, and it can be used as property? Interesting.

Comment: @kapep: Only when used in string notation: `a = {'#' : 1}`. `a.#` will return: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` (`a['#']` is okay)

Comment: @user, your question has been put on hold because it does not contain a critical piece of information. **This does not mean it is the end for your question, or that you should give up on it.** Instead, please edit your question to add the information requested (basically the code around `_###`), so it can be understood, reopened and answered.

Comment: `_###` is between quotes, so it is a String.

Comment: @Murali I found it here:http://images.apple.com/v/macbook-pro/e/scripts/features_retina.js

Comment: I think it's a part of a string rapresenting a canvas path/keyframe

Comment: `var i=m+e+"_###"+g;`. The code there is just storing a few concatenated variables in `i`. The string happens to contain `"_###"`.

Comment: `var i=m+e+"_###"+g;` Looks like they are concatenating strings. What is the confusion?

Comment: @Murali I didn't understand because that link does not exist on the apple site, so why would they make a link in there script which does not exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the relevant code part:

```
init: function () {
    var g = ".jpg";
    var f = (!AC.Environment.Feature.isHandheld() && AC.Environment.Feature.isRetina()) ? "_2x" : "";
    var m = "/105/media/us/macbook-pro/2013/flash_hero_flow" + f + "/";
    var e = "flash_hero_flow" + f;
    var k = AC.require("flow/playerFactory");
    var h = new AC.ShowOnScroll(v, {
        threshold: 0.9,
        timeInView: 0.5
    });
    var l = [m + e + "_keyframe" + g, m + e + "_endframe" + g];
    var i = m + e + "_###" + g;
    var j = m + e + "_manifest.json";
    this.flow = k(v, l, i, j, {
        superframes: false,
        keyframeCache: false,
        benchmark: false
    });
    this.flow.frameRate = 30;
    this.flow.on("canplaythrough", function () {
        h.setDelegate({
            visitorEngaged: function () {
                x.flow.play()
            }
        })
    })
}
```

It will create an URL that will either be `/105/media/us/macbook-pro/2013/flash_hero_flow/flash_hero_flow_###.jpg` or `/105/media/us/macbook-pro/2013/flash_hero_flow/flash_hero_flow_2x_###.jpg`. The URL is then passed to some initialization function that, based on the property name, looks like it could be part of [flow player](http://flash.flowplayer.org/), a popular flash video player.

> that link does not exist on the apple site

The URL is relative to the page, so it depends on which domain the script will be embedded. It could also be that the *flow* application already has some base URL set by other scripts on the same page.

Also note that the fragment part denoted by the first `#` is usually not send to the server. This would mean that `###.jpg` could be ignored, which seems a bit strange. I think it's more likely that `###` is a placeholder that will be replaced with something else in a later step.